# PHP script occasionally waits 20-30 minutes to start

Tags: php, apache, http, post

I have a PHP script on my server that, primarily, takes files from an upload and moves them into place. It usually works fine, but occasionally, the script won't start for 20-30 minutes. The entire uploaded files will be sitting in the tmp folder during the wait, so it seems like the data transfer is complete. Here is an excerpt from the Apache access log indicating a POST to the script (from an Android app)...

```
[29/Nov/2011:11:21:55 -0500] "POST /submit.php HTTP/1.1" ...
```

However, this entry doesn't show up in the access log until 11:43 or so, surrounded by other page requests from 11:43:42 and 12:00:02. This leads me to believe the entry doesn't get written until the script executes, but it is written with the time of submission. Here's the error log, where I'm writing events from the script...

```
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] Script started: Nov 29, 2011 11:43:19
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] Audio file provided
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] Timestamp provided
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] Defaults set
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] Connected to database
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] Database selected
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] Query successful
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] 551: ID set
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] 551: Audio file moved
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] 551: Algorithm succeeded
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] 551: Algorithm query succeeded
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:19 2011] 551: Photo type identified
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:20 2011] 551: Photo and thumbnail saved
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:20 2011] 551: Cache cleared
[Tue Nov 29 11:43:20 2011] Script finished: Nov 29, 2011 11:43:20
```

Any idea what would cause a PHP script to not execute for so long, or what kind of logging I should put in place to find out? The server is running `Ubuntu 10.04`, `Apache 2.2.14`, and `PHP 5.3.2`.

Comment: This should probably go to http://serverfault.com ?

Comment: How big of a file was uploaded in that case?  The script wont start until apache has received the entire file, and Apache wont write to the access log until the request is complete so it can write the http response code in the access log along with the request (e.g. 200 OK or 500 Error).  I would guess in that case it took about 21 minutes to upload the file before PHP was called.

Comment: The files are around 0.5 MB. The full-size files are sitting in the tmp folder on the server, waiting to be moved into place by PHP, so I'm fairly certain it's not a slow upload.

Answer (score 0):

You should really check your server's memory - if you upload more than the memory can handle, you may have a problem. PHP puts all uploaded files in the memory before it actually saves them and if this has to be written to a swap file first, you'll see these issues you're describing.

Comment: Do you think 0.5 MB files could do this though? The Android client submits one entry, waits for the response from the server, and submits another. Is there a log I should check or put in place to look for memory problems?

Comment: While it's uploading simply check the memory usage.